# Is there a way to animate the HERE Android SDK marker movement on the map?

Tags: android, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I am trying to animate MapMarker object movement between two point on the map.
This is line that sets new position but without animation.

```
marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker?hl=en#Marker.setAnimation but it looks like continuous animation

Maybe you can create manually your own animation with PropertyAnimator or something else and calculating progress of changing position